# COBOL cursor Using IN operator in the WHERE clause

Tags: sql, oracle, cobol, where-in

I have an issue that I can't seem to figure out and wonder if it is a limitation in the environment, or something simple I haven't thought of.

I am running in AIX, using Microfocus Cobol with imbedded Oracle SQL in the program.

Today this SQL is running against the entire table(s) for production runs which is as designed.  When running this same program for a production-test system we don't need to have a full set of results returned...we only need the records returned for the client(s) in that production-test run.

So it is easy enough to add a statement into the SQL to limit it like as follows:

```
AND OLM.SYS_TX IN ('8220,8245,8993')
```

That works just fine if I can get the value(s) into the query.

The issue is we never know how many of these 4 digit client values are going to be in each run.  Could be a single one, could be a 30 of them.  We never know until we start each production-test run.

My solution was to create a file out in the AIX Korn Shell Script of these numbers, pass them into the COBOL module by ACCEPTing them via an ENVIRONMENT-NAME variable, formatting them inside the program, and then using that formatted field in the SQL as such:

```
AND HIT.SYS_TX IN (:WS-CLIENT-NOS)
```

However, I can't get the the SQL to recognize the CLIENT NOs into that query!

Example:

Korn Shell Script prepares a field with the following in it:

```
8220,8396,8529,8685,8499,8218,8383,8150,8778,8255,8773,8993,8299
```

The COBOL program accepts this line, and formats a new one to use in the SQL.
I have looped through the numbers above counting how many non-space characters I am have, then I use a STRING command to format a new line to use in the SQL.  So after formatting I have this:

```
'8220,8396,8529,8685,8499,8218,8383,8150,8778,8255,8773,8993,8299'
```

Which resides in WORKING STORAGE field -  WS-CLIENT-NOS

And that field is used in the following CURSOR:

```
EXEC SQL DECLARE PRETEST_EXT_HIT_LIST_CSR CURSOR FOR
SELECT HIT.ACCOUNT_NUMBER,
      HIT.SYS_TX,
      HIT.PRIN_TX,
      LPAD(NVL(RANK, 99999),5, 0),
      NON_OPTIONAL,
      LPAD(LOC.LOCATION_ID, 10, 0),
      LPAD (TRIM (ITEM_ID), 10, '0'),
      TO_CHAR (HIT.START_DT, 'YYYYMMDD'),
      EXT_CLIENT_HIT_LIST_PK
  FROM OLM_MSG_MASTER OMM,
       EXT_CLIENT_HIT_LIST HIT,
       OLM_LOCATIONS LOC
  WHERE DECODE(TRIM(TRANSLATE(item_id,'0123456789',' ')),
               NULL, 'number','contains char') = 'number'
    AND LOC.OLM_LOCATIONS_PK = OMM.OLM_LOCATIONS_FK
    AND OLM_MSG_MASTER_PK = ITEM_ID
    AND APPLICATION_ID = 'MMSG'
    AND HIT.START_DT <=
            TO_DATE (:HV-PROCESS-DATE, 'MMDDYYYY')
    AND (HIT.END_DT IS NULL
      OR HIT.END_DT >=
            TO_DATE (:HV-PROCESS-DATE, 'MMDDYYYY'))
    AND HIT.SYS_TX IN (:WS-CLIENT-NOS)    <============================
ORDER BY HIT.SYS_TX, HIT.PRIN_TX, HIT.ACCOUNT_NUMBER,
         ITEM_ID
END-EXEC.
```

But the Query doesn't return any results.

- If I hardcode the same data into the IN (' ') structure then I get
  results, so my structure and formatting is good.
- If I hardcode the ' ' marks into the cursor and not in the
  working-storage field I get no results.
- If I put the ( ) in the Working-Storage fields and not hardcoded into
  the SQL then it won't compile.
- If I change the relational operator to '=' instead of "IN" and use a
  single value instead it will pull results.
- If I hardcode it to concatenate lots of "OR" statements it will work
  and pull results.  But that isn't practical for COBOL.
- But if I try to put my properly (allegedly) formatted line of data
  into that "IN" clause it doesn't work!

Any help or tricks would be very appreciated!  Even if this is something that can't be done!

Mark

Comment: Not so much knowledge about cobol, but sql: your in list may look like (to show my point i reduced the list)....... where field in ( 8220,8396,8529) or ....... where field in ( '8220', '8396', '8529' ) but never: ....... where field in ( '8220,8396,8529' )  the in clause must be formatted correct. And afaik the in list is limited to 1000 elements. so be careful if you have more, use a join.

Comment: I would of thought you would need to code it like `HIT.SYS_TX IN (:WS-CLIENT-NO1, :WS-CLIENT-NO2, ..... :WS-CLIENT-NO*)`, currently you are asking if `HIT.SYS_TX = :WS-CLIENT-NOS`.  Loading a temporary table like Bobc should work. Can not comment on Gordons answer

Answer (score 1):

The best approach in my opinion is to create a table to put your 4 digit numbers in and then simply do a join to this table. It's likely to be easier and better performing, as the optimizer will have a good shot at getting the right cardinality. 
There are a couple of ways you can implement this

1. Use a Global Temporary Table (GTT); the data is session private.
2. The table has a (for example "session") identifier that is part of join key.

Comment: While this looks nice it is likely not possible - if you do multiple production runs at the same time this technique won't help you.

Comment: @SimonSobisch Can you elaborate why?

Comment: If you don't create a table specific for each run then multiple runs will use/mix their 4 digit numbers: 1st run writes three numbers, starts; 2nd run writes 512 numbers; starts; 3rd run writes 5 numbers but as the 2nd run isn't finished yet it uses the wrong numbers now.
Or do you suggest to create and use a different table for each run?

Comment: @SimonSobisch There are two simple approaches. 1. Use a Global Temporary Table (GTT); the data is session private. 2. The table has a (for example "session") identifier that is part of join key.  You *could* use a different table for each run, but that becomes messy, since you now have to name each table differently

Comment: correct - I suggest to add this to the answer via Edit :-)

Comment: @SimonSobisch Done. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that this statement:

```
HIT.SYS_TX IN (:WS-CLIENT-NOS)
```

is really equivalent to:

```
HIT.SYS_TX = :WS-CLIENT-NOS
```

Instead, you can use `like` or regular expressions:

```
:WS-CLIENT-NOS '%,' || HIT.SYS_TX || ',%'
```

or

```
regexp_like(HIT.SYS_TX, '^' || replace(:WS-CLIENT-NOS, ',', '|') || '$')
```

There are actually other methods of converting the list to a table of some sort.  However, the above methods only involve changing one line of code.